# Apply simply query filter using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was looking for long time, but cant find proper answer, how to, in the simplest way, change one field filter criteria in Query using VBA.

I.e. I have "Orders" query. I want to run VBA and filter "[OrderID] = 12345".
Thanks!

Comment: I think easiest way would be executing the SQL code of your query from VBA, and adding a WHERE parameter to specify the criteria.

Comment: It depends on the context - of which you mention nothing.